# Visual Studio Code setting keybindings for tasks

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

So I have been trying to set two shortcuts for two tasks on VS Code. One is for compiling a java program and the other is for running it. But I can't get it work for some reason. 
I saved this code in my keybindings.json file.

```
{
"key": "ctrl+alt+c",
"command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
"args": "JC"}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?
Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: That is the correct keybinding, assuming the task `label` is `JC`.  Does the task run if you start it through the command palette `run task` command?  And do you have an extension that also uses that keybinding?

Comment: Yes, I have a shortcut to run tasks. But Im looking for assigning key bindings for running specific tasks. For instance, ctrl+alt+c for compiling and ctrl+alt+r for running.

Comment: As I said, your keybinding is in the correct format.  There is some other issue.